# Wubi installing problem(Wubi doesn't appear on Boot Screen)

Tags: 12.04, wubi, bootloader

I have this problem. The other days i had some problem with my Ubuntu installation, problems with grub2 and so on. Now the problem i have is: on the boot screen appears windows and ubuntu, but ubuntu is not working because i uninstall it as in a tutorial found here. You know how can I do that? And i have another problem i start to install wubi inside Windows, it's shows installing, show the reboot, i reboot, and after reboot nothing happens? Any ideas how can i make it working? I mean i don't know if in 12.04 it should still do something, but it doesn't appear on the bootscreen as well. On the boot screen i have Windows and the previously uninstalled Ubuntu.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The grub menu is hidden by default on Wubi installs. If you hold down the `Shift` key after selecting Ubuntu it should appear. If you're getting a blank screen after selecting Ubuntu it might be a graphics card issue - what specs do you have?

Comment: I am telling you. There is not appearing the Ubuntu in the boot screen!

Comment: I think you mentioned you have a Win7 install. Please go to an administrator command prompt and edit your question with the output from `bcdedit`. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wubi modifies your windows bootloader to chainload its own bootloader, then boots from there. Select the windows boot option, then select ubuntu from there.

Comment: This is what i am telling you. Is not appearing on boot option screen. This is what i am trying to solve, but no luck yet!

Comment: on grub or ntldr/bcd?

Comment: no grub appears, only windows boot loader!